# How to maintain the proper lifecycle of RxDataStore<Preferences> In Multiple Activities In Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, datastore, android-jetpack-datastore

There is a `DataStoreManager` class that is used to create an DataStore Preferences file in Android app as this is an alternative of the deprecated SharedPreferences.

```
public class DataStoreManager {
public static final DataStoreManager instance = new DataStoreManager();

    private static final Handler dataStoreManagerHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    private DataStoreManager() {
    }

    private RxDataStore<Preferences> dataStore;

    public void init(Context context) {
        dataStore = new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(context, "preferences_datastore").build();
    }

    public void saveValue(String keyName, String Value) {
        Preferences.Key<String> key = new Preferences.Key<>(keyName);

        dataStore.updateDataAsync(preferences -> {
            MutablePreferences mutablePreferences = preferences.toMutablePreferences();
            String currentKey = preferences.get(key);

            if (currentKey == null) {
                saveValue(keyName, Value);
            }
            mutablePreferences.set(key, currentKey != null ? Value : "");
            return Single.just(mutablePreferences);
        }).subscribe();
    }

    public void getStringValue(String keyName, StringValueDelegate stringValueDelegate) {
        Preferences.Key<String> key = new Preferences.Key<>(keyName);

        dataStore.data().map(preferences -> preferences.get(key))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                        s.request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        dataStoreManagerHandler.post(() -> stringValueDelegate.onGetValue(s));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                });
    }

    public interface StringValueDelegate {
        void onGetValue(String s);
    }
}
```

I have to ***save and retrieve the DataStore Preferences from multiple Activities*** of the project using the following code.

```
DataStoreManager.instance.init(getApplicationContext());
DataStoreManager.instance.saveValue("schoolName", schoolName);
```

for retrieving

```
DataStoreManager.instance.getStringValue("schoolName", schoolName -> {
            schoolName = schoolName;
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: schoolName: " + schoolName);
            textClasses.setText(schoolName);
        });
```

I am facing the following error:-

```
You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).
```